# Get value from every textbox on page

Tags: php, html

I am programming a page right now, and I am stuck with a problem.
The thing is that I am making a page, where you can answer all kind of question, but as it is possible to make new questions for that page, I am not able to keep a track of every input box, as it can't be something manual.

Let us say that i have the textboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="question_1" />
<input type="text" name="question_2" />
<input type="text" name="question_3" />
<input type="text" name="question_4" />
```

But as I add more questions from another page, with help from MySQL, there come new fields, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="question_5" />
<input type="text" name="question_6" />
<input type="text" name="question_7" />
```

As there can come unlimited questions, I cant really get their values by making PHP string like these:

```
$question1 = $_POST["question_1"];
$question2 = $_POST["question_2"];
$question3 = $_POST["question_3"];
```

and so on, because I can't know how many there are going to be made.

So my question is: Is it possible to get the value of every input box, which name is starting with "question_" and store them in a variable?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
$myarray = [];
while ($_POST["questions_".$i]) {
    $i++;
    array_push($myarray, $_POST["questions_".$i]);
}
```

Loop thru them until it's null. This pushes them to an array, but you could use them in the loop.

You can then generate a string from those too, for example a MySQL query:

```
$i = 1;
$firstpartofquery = "";
$secondpartofquery = "";
while ($_POST["questions_".$i]) {
    $i++;
    if ($firstpartofquery) { $firstpartofquery .= ", "; }
    $firstpartofquery .= "question_" . $i;
    if ($secondpartofquery) { $firstpartofquery .= ", "; }
    $secondpartofquery .= "'" . $_POST["questions_".$i] . "'";
}
$myquery = "INSERT INTO question($firstpartofquery) VALUES($secondpartofquery)";
```

Comment: That `!` is prolly a typo and you should add `isset`'s to prevent notices

Comment: Yup. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it gave me some ideas that i could start with. But now i need to insert the values to their seperate fields in the mysql database. Because i got a table named "questions", and there are fields named the same as the input boxes. So i need to somehow transfer the values that i got here, to the database, but i dont know how. I cant think of how to make it work, like mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO question (question_1, question_2m ..) VALUES ('" . $_POST["question_$i"] . "', '" . $_POST["question_$i"] . "', ..)");, but that is not correct.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can append to a string (or 2) instead of adding to an array. See my edit.

Comment: @bjb568 It gives me this string: INSERT INTO question(2, 3, , 4, , 5, ) VALUES('answer1''answer2''answer3'''), which isn't correct in mysql. It start of with 2, and not 1, though it is selected. And also if i choose to answer the question 1, 2 and then 4, without answering 3, it doesn't even return any inputs, as if you need to answer them all. Also, it makes the "3, , 4," in the first part, which is weird, because it doesn't make sence. The last thing is that it doesnt write question_ infront of the number, in the first part. Is there any way this could be fixed, because i have tried anything

Comment: I have fixed the thing where it didn't write "question_" in the start. It was because of the + instead of . at "$firstpartofquery .= "question_" + $i;"

Answer (score 1):

Just name you all of form's input elements as `question[]`

i.e

```
<input type="text" name="question[]" />
<input type="text" name="question[]" />
<input type="text" name="question[]" />
```

Then from your script you can loop through them, something like the following,:

```
$questions = $_POST['question'];    
foreach ($questions as $question){    
   echo $question." <br /> \n";
}
```

This solution make life easier if you want to handle those fields on the [client-side](/questions/tagged/client-side) i.e via [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) for example, you will be able to handle them easily as:

```
<script>
questions = document.getElementsByName('question[]');
</script>
```

So by this way you have an array of all objects -fields- that contain your questions. As I think, that's the standard solution for handling multiple fields of the same entity in your forms.